# Implementation of gojs with angular4

Tags: angular, gojs

I am very new to angular. I need to implement the flowchart of GoJS with my angular 4 code. I  have searched a lot but unfortunately unable to find references. Can somebody help me with these step wise procedure for implementing it.

I have found only this angular 1 link .
https://github.com/NorthwoodsSoftware/GoJS/blob/master/samples/angular.html

Comment: this [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq) might help check how to import third party js with angular

Comment: Did you find the Angular 4 project at https://github.com/NorthwoodsSoftware/GoJS/tree/master/projects/angular-basic ?